# Wait for async function in multiple places

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

With Promises I can have two separate "threads" both waiting for the same value:

```js
let trigger;
const promise = new Promise(r => {
  console.log('promise is created *once*');
  trigger = value => {
    console.log('trigger is called *once*');
    r(value);
  }
});

(async () => {
  console.log('A waiting');
  const value = await promise;
  console.log(`A finished, got ${value}`);
})();

(async () => {
  console.log('B waiting');
  const value = await promise;
  console.log(`B finished, got ${value}`);
})();

trigger('hello');
console.log('And *two* things are waiting on the single promise');
```

I've tried to replicate this with async/await but to no avail.

The following snippet does not work:

```js
let trigger = async () => {
  console.log('trigger should be called *once*');
  return 'hello';
};

(async () => {
  console.log('A waiting');
  const value = await trigger; // <-- What do I need to put here?
  console.log(`A finished, got ${value}`);
})();

(async () => {
  console.log('B waiting');
  const value = await trigger; // <-- What do I need to put here?
  console.log(`B finished, got ${value}`);
})();

trigger(); // <-- How can this "kick off" the two awaits above?
```

Is it possible to write the same functionality in the first snippet, using async/await?

I'm okay with falling back to using Promise if that's needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To `await`, you need to have a reference to the singular promise, so you can't call a function on demand and have that function create a promise and then use that same promise elsewhere (unless the function that creates the promise also holds it in state to return to other callers, like a singleton).

I'd create a singular promise initially, and then send it to the async functions:

```js
const trigger = async () => {
  console.log('trigger should be called *once*');
  return 'hello';
};

async function as1(prom) {
  console.log('A waiting');
  const value = await prom;
  console.log(`A finished, got ${value}`);
}

async function as2(prom) {
  console.log('B waiting');
  const value = await prom;
  console.log(`B finished, got ${value}`);
}

const thePromise = trigger();
as1(thePromise);
as2(thePromise);
```

Don't use `async` just to return a promise, though - if the purpose of a function is to create a promise, then do it explicitly - that way, it's more clear what your code is meant to do. Async and await *have not* made the Promise keyword obsolete, it's just syntax sugar which is useful in some situations (and unnecessary in others).

Comment: A ha. That makes sense. I could wrap the `async function as1` and `async function as2` with a single utility which takes the promise as an argument, and returns a function which awaits the promise for me. So all that duplicate logic is in one place. I think I'll do that.